# Every isomorphism of commutative ring with 1 with product of two rings is defined by idempotent element $x$ and element $1-x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I proved that $f: R \rightarrow P_x \times P_{x\prime}$ where $x$ is impodent element in $R$, $x\prime=(1-x)$ (also impodent) and $P_x=\{rx:r \in R\}$.
But I have problem with proving that every isomorphism of ring with product of two rings is defined by idempotent element and it's opposite element.

Comment: Please write the question also in the body, not just in the title.

Comment: Let $\varphi: R_1\stackrel{\sim}{\to}R_2\times R_3$ be an isomorphism. Now consider $\varphi^{-1}(1,0)$ and $\varphi^{-1}(0,1)$.

Comment: So, find an element $x$ that maps into $x=(1,0)$ and another element that maps into $y=(0,1)$, prove that $x+y=1$ and then prove that the isomorphism must be given by $r\mapsto (rx, ry)$ and you are done.